# Temperature control fails. Will a PID solve the problem?

Tags: temperature, pid-controller

I made a temperature control system without PID (just on/off with an offset) to control the temperature in a tank.

I can only cool the tank with a cooling coil inside the tank (so there is no heating element.) However, I can never reach the target temperature 20C due to the remaining cold water inside the coil (although the pump which transfer the cooling water inside the coil is turned off,) so the temperature drops after some hour or hours below 20C.

If I buy a commercial PID controller can I solve the problem?

If not, what can I do?

Comment: No, PID won’t help if the sense temp is wrong. Keep the pump or another low power pump flowing to circulate fluid to sensor to read temperature better. The “plant is so slow” that. All you need is P and not PID with a small amount of hysteresis to suit desired tolerance and motor cycle rate to extend the life of the pump.

Comment: So, the thermal mass of static cold water causes your temperature to drop below your desired set-point?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 If I understood the question correctly, the issue is that the cooling element remains cold after the surrounding water have reached the target, continuing to cool it down. Better circulation or better sensing will help a bit, but not entirely. I think it needs to be calibrated to take this offset in account. But without heating element it will never be perfect.

Comment: Ok if there is a large gap between coil and sensor Kd will assist that. But choosing the T sense location is key , because  the mass of the coil is smaller than the tank not too close, yet not too far away from rise time issues from dispersion. In a house the sensor is far enough away from the ducts to give at least 10minute cycle time. 1 minute is too fast and 20 minutes too slow. Yours may vary

Comment: "choosing the T sense location is key"  yes, this

Comment: You can always work out the detailed residual cooling (over time) caused by the cold water in the coil once the circulation ceases. That knowledge can be developed independent of the sensor position. (There are Fourier methods -- which were developed originally for similar purposes in fact -- you could use to truly nail it down well if you felt like it.) With detailed knowledge, you can design a proper system including the sensor positioning. There are people who do exactly this kind of thing as a regular job. Get Numerical Recipes (book) for methods. May need custom code.

Comment: I can not understand what is your proposals. Sorry

Comment: @hmmy92 That's okay. You asked for a commercial solution anyway. Just ignore me.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain the relative volumes of water in the tank and in the cooling coil. A dimensioned drawing would help.

Answer (score 1):

> just on/off with an offset

You probably mean an ON/OFF controller with hysteresis? The ON/OFF controller is always stable, meanwhile the PID is not. The PID controller has to be tuned to work properly. It can be very painful to properly tune it, even for an engineer that has a big theoretical knowledge on closed loop control. The ON/OFF control drawback compared to PID, is that ON/OFF control produces higher overshoots/undershoots as it is constantly oscillating around the setpoint value, but for rude regulation it is OK. Also not complicated, easy to setup.

If this kind of control can't provide a stable oscillating control value around setpoint, neither a PID would be able to control.

Comment: 1. If you define stability condition as the amplitude of the limit cycle less than X, then PID and similar can do better.  2. modern "PID" controllers have many other features, like rate limits and sometimes setpoint filter, that reduce the shortcomings of PI without D, for ease of use. also ctrlr features can address the heat/cool asymmetry  3. autotune ..... the cost is complexity with typically 40 parameters in a single loop controller to wonder about

Comment: @PeteW ON/OFF control is ALWAYS stable, while the P, PI, PID, PD can be become unstable no matter what countermeasures you introduce. The true fact is that more gain makes the loop more dynamic and susceptible to unstability, low gain makes it unresponsible. I tell you again: ON/OFF control is ALWAYS stable.

Comment: yes, but I don't think unbounded instability was the original problem

Comment: @MarkoBuršič So you say that is difficult to tune a PID for this purpose?

Comment: @hmmy92 Most autotuning PIDs calculate parameters so that start with on/off control mode. If the on/off control doesn't work for you, then there is no such other known controller that will do the magic.

Comment: So I can not just somehow to tune my commercial PID to take into consideration that the coil remains cold so that the the pump to turn off in 23C (a random number) and after some time I can know that the temperature will drop to the target (20C)? I understand that needs a lot of calculations in order to estimate the turn off value which I assume is difficult to be always the same (due to environmental parameters)

Comment: @hmmy92 No, that's a most challenging system, with a dead time. You would require a special controller, like Smith Predictor, one could make a dissertation on that. Predictive controllers have to have an exact model of the system, lots of studies and measurements, expensive programs like MATLAB, then you simulate and deploy to a target system - this is a yet expensive industrial computer. But you should edit your question, with a drawing, a photo maybe. You could indroduce somewhere an extra sensor, then maybe a cascade control loop or feedforward path and P-control.There is no description,

Comment: @Marko, let's not overstate the difficulty. It is temperature control of a bath or tank etc, a common application. It suffers from combination of what is in essence lag due to transport delay, and probably would also have overshoot from shortcomings of the controller. There were good suggestions above, especially (in my opinion) optimizing the placement of the sensor. Various controller features can correct the transport delay, prevent overshoot, and ease the tuning process (i.e. empirically characterize the lag, no need to make it too complicated).

Comment: @PeteW The heat exchanger has a fast response VS. the OP words. So it's not plausible that a pipe with filled cold water without a flow could cool down a tank for hours more. Something is wrong with the setup, observations,...etc. I do agree with the comments of other users, further I want to make the OP clear that buying a general PID controller won't help too much before the very basic things are not clear.

Comment: @Marko -- that makes sense

Comment: @MarkoBuršič what is VS and OP?

Comment: @hmmy92 VS = versus, compared to; OP = Original Poster, in this case you are

Answer (score 0):

This will sound a little counter-intuitive, but adding a very slight amount of constant heating, so that the cooling control loop has something to work against, might be something to explore.